# KNN Algorithm in Weka Never Completing On Large Dataset

Tags: algorithm, weka, data-mining, knn, large-data

back with a question on datamining and working with Weka and WekaSharp on datamining. Through WekaSharp I have been doing some analysis on a fairly large dataset which is the KDD Cup 1999 10% database ( ~70 mb). I have had good results with the decision tree J48 algorithm and the Naive Bayes algorithm each taking between 10 and 30 min to complete. When I run this same data through the KNN algorithm and it never finishes the analysis, it does not error out it simply runs forever. I have tried all different parameters with no effect. When I run the same KNN algorithm on a smaller sample dataset such as the iris.arff it finishes with no difficulty. Here is the setup I have for the KNN  parameters:
 "-K 1 -W 0 -A \"weka.core.neighboursearch.KDTree -A \\"weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last\\"\"" 
Is there an inherent issue with KNN and large datasets or is there a setup issue? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kNN is subject to the "curse of dimensionality": spatial queries of high-dimensional datasets cannot be effectively optimized in the same way lower-dimensional datasets can, turning them effectively into brute-force searches.

NB laughs at dimensionality because it basically ignores dimensions. Many decision tree variants are also fairly good at dealing with high-dimensional data. kNN does not like high-dimensional data. Expect to wait for a long time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and comment this was a very useful insight and something that makes a lot of sense in terms of distance measures. More than likely I will choose a different algoritem as I want to be able to do lots of runs over these sets. Thank you again.

Comment: Hello, Just as an update I let the algorithm run to completion in F# and so far the sequential time has averaged at 53 hours to finish. So it does finish eventually :-).